# Create and write function for pipe for usage in main()

Tags: c

The '`create_andWrite`' function should create a pipe and write a string to it. The child process which is created in the main should read from the pipe.

I only worked with pipes in one method(e.g. read and write are both in main) before and I'm really struggling with this one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
int creat_and_write(FILE *fd, char *string) {}    
int main() {
    int fd[2];
    creat_and_write();
    int p = fork;
}
```

These are my functions signatures so far

Comment: What would you like to do if the string length of the message to write is very long?  That is, if it is bigger than the pipe buffer and write to the pipe blocks?

Comment: "*I only worked with pipes in one method*". Please show that code. If it indeed works then writing a function is just a matter of refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

Pipes are one way of unidirectional IPC, used usually with fork() to pass data in a sort of vertical hierarchy.
Hope the example below is clear. and spot the usage of the 2 functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define READ_END 0
#define WRITE_END 1

// pipe uses file descriptors to communicate between processes not pointers to files.
int creat_and_write(int *fd, char *string) {
    // first and formost we need a pipe.
     if (pipe(fd) == -1) {
        perror("pipe error");
        exit(1);
    }
    // now the fd contains 2 file descriptors, one for reading and one for writing to the pipe.
    // we fork a child process which will inherit most internals including the pipe's file descriptors.
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1)
    {
        perror("fork error");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (pid == 0) 
    {
        // we're at the child process.
        // now we can write to the write end of the pipe
        write(fd[WRITE_END], string, strlen(string));
        // good practice to close done end of the pipe. for a full cleanup.
        close(fd[WRITE_END]);
    }
    else 
    {
        // we're at the parent process.
        // now we can read from the read end of the pipe
        char buffer[strlen(string)];
        read(fd[READ_END], buffer, 100);
        close(fd[READ_END]);
        printf("now at the parent process: %s\n", buffer);
    }
    return 0;
}    
int main() {
    int fd[2];
    creat_and_write(fd, "msg from child process");
    return 0;
}
```